# Issue with kernel header files for installing VirtualBox on Debian

Tags: debian, kernel, virtualbox

im trying to install virtual box-5.2 (got the .deb file from the website) on my Debian 9 stretch. Currently I have the Kernel: Linux 4.9.0

When I run: `sudo dpkg -I virtualbox-5.2_5.2.12-122591~Debian~stretch_amd64.deb` I get following error message:

```
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
/sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

But when I am trying to install or upgrade the header files with: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, linux tells me, that the header files are already installed. And when I run `/sbin/vboxconfig`I get the same error message as above.

Could anyone help with this issue? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `gdebi` it should pull in all dependencies.

However I added virtual-box to `/etc/apt/source.list.d/virtual-box.apt-sources.list`

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jessie contrib" |sudo tee /etc/apt/source.list.d/virtual-box.apt-sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.2 #would be nice if we could just specify the series.
```

Comment: The same error message occurs! Even installing with gdebi. The error message also says, that the group vboxusers already exists. Could this mean something?

Comment: `vboxusers already exists` is not an error. You can ignore it. I have no idea for the rest, as I did it as outlined above.

Comment: No need to use `gdebi`. After invoking `dpkg -i`, you could only do `apt -f install` to force the installation of dependencies. Be careful with this answer, because you are actually promoting two ideas: one is to use `gdebi` with the file downloaded from the website and to install it from a `apt` repository. It's not the same.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes if you haven't `rebooted` after installation, so that should be it.

```
#shutdown -r now OR #reboot
```

then as root or sudo rum:

```
#vboxconfig
```

Also be sure you have the development-tools installed:

```
#sudo apt update
#sudo apt install build-essential
```